# Application server or Web-server performance wise which one is better?

Tags: performance, webserver, application-server

I am confused between is application server better or web server ?

In which scenario we should use application server and web server?

I read that application server has web server so web server performance is better?

I also read application server doesn't hit database if same query is requested by client so I am confused.